# how to use multiple formatting options in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

i want to accommodate $/£ with Bn/M to a label in d3.

examples
$100M
£45Bn

currently for me it is only supporting one either (prefix symbols) or (Postfix symbols)

example
$100
45Bn

in short is it possible to use more than one (multiple) formatting options in d3?

Comment: Could you split your data and format them separately?

Comment: could you please explain it a lil' bit more

Comment: There are many ways you could go about this and without seeing your code and / or data it is quite difficult to point you in the right direction.

Comment: var lg = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('transform', centerTx); 
      lg.selectAll('text')
      .data(ticks)
      //.enter().append('minValue')
      .enter().append('text')
       .attr('transform', function(d) {
        //var com=0;
        
       var ratio = scale(d);
       var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
       return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
       
      })
      .text(function(d) { return sym + d; })

Comment: sym can b anything $/£ d is the data  referring to the last line of the code .text(function(d) { return sym + d; }) how to add M/Bn to this

Answer (score 0):

D3 adds the currency symbol as per locale, so you will have only one. You can create your own formatter function for that purpose. For instance, you could use:

```
function formatCurrency(d) {
    return '$' + d3.formatPrefix(d) + ' £' + d3.formatPrefix(ratio * d);
}
```

Where `ratio` is the factor to convert from dollars to pounds. This function can be used as `formatCurrency(1000000)` or as a tick formatter for the axes of a chart. Regards,

Comment: hey thank you so much for your help. i am trying to follow your method. but i have figured that i want to read the prefix value inside  d3.format function. but what i discovered is that this function takes takes only one parameter to which i am currently passing the scale param. so my mission is to pass a variable containing the symbol to the d3.format function along with the sufix (scale) param. please help me figure how do i pass the value . thanks and regards.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, can you share the relevant code and desired results?